# maximum range of projectile launched from elevation

Tags: physics, intuition, classical-mechanics, kinematics, projectile-motion

I am trying to find the maximum range of projectile from an elevation. I found the answer in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/127300/21813), but I have two questions:

1. Why does $y$ need to be $0?$
2. Why do they differentiate with respect to $\theta,$ and what is the meaning of this?

Comment: 1. The projectile falls when $y=0$, which corresponds level of elevation foot. 2. The projectile can be shot with various angles $\theta$ and distance from elevation foot depends on this angle. So to find maximum distance we can differentiate with respect to theta and solve $x_{fall}'(\theta)=0$ for $\theta$. There is also more simple approach, allowing avoid hard calculations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1. Why does $y$ need to be $0?$

Because the projectile's **range** $R$ is its horizontal distance travelled, which is precisely its $x$-coordinate at its landing point, that is, when there is no elevation, that is, when $y=0.$

> 2. Why do they differentiate with respect to $\theta,$ and what is the meaning of this?

The projectile's **range** $R$ varies according to its launch angle $\theta,$ so is **maximised** when $\frac{\mathrm dR}{\mathrm d\theta}$ equals zero. (Consider the graph of $R$ against $\theta;$ $R$ attains its maximum value when its gradient $\frac{\mathrm dR}{\mathrm d\theta}$ equals zero.)

P.S. I am the author of the cited Question; even though I accepted Patrick's Answer, please treat [my self-Answer there](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4280938/21813) as the natural continuation of the work that I'd started in the Question.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation

Comment: How'd it feel when a 10 year old question found use again?

Answer (score 3):

Let projectile to be shot at angle $\theta$. Then $x=ut\cos\theta$, $y=H+ut\sin\theta - \frac{gt^2}{2}$. From first equation $t=\frac{x}{u\cos \theta}$, then $y=H+x \tan\theta-\frac{gx^2}{2u^2\cos^2\theta}=H+x \tan\theta-\frac{gx^2}{2u^2}(1+\tan^2\theta)$.

Range of projectile at some $\theta$ is $x$ at which $y=0$. Then range $R$ is defined by $H+R\tan\theta-\frac{gR^2}{2u^2}(1+\tan^2\theta)=0$. Let mark $\tan\theta=p$, then $H+Rp-\frac{gR^2}{2u^2}(1+p^2)=0$.

Let consider this equation with respect to $p$ and rewrite it as $$\frac{gR^2}{2u^2}p^2-Rp+\left(\frac{gR^2}{2u^2}-H\right)=0.$$ Solution for $p$ will exist if $$D=R^2-4\frac{gR^2}{2u^2}\left(\frac{gR^2}{2u^2}-H\right)\geq 0$$

$$R^2>0\Rightarrow 1-4\frac{g}{2u^2}\left(\frac{gR^2}{2u^2}-H\right) \geq 0\Rightarrow \frac{gR^2}{2u^2}-H \leq \frac{u^2}{2g} \Rightarrow R^2\leq \frac{u^4}{g^2}+\frac{2u^2}{g}H$$ $$R\leq \sqrt{\frac{u^4}{g^2}+\frac{2u^2}{g}H}=\frac{u}{g}\sqrt{u^2+2gH}$$