# Solving 2 equations (Projectile motion)

Tags: physics

The question is from Physics, but all I need is help on solving maths. So basically, i am trying to find out the optimal angle for projectile motion from a certain height and I end up with these two equations:

$$0=h + R \tan \theta - R^2 \frac g{2u^2}(1 + \tan^2 \theta) \tag1$$

$$R= \frac{g}{u^2}cot \theta \tag2$$
where, h = height of the tower

R= maximum distance travelled by the stone (Range)

g=gravitational constant

$\theta$ =  angle of the projection

Can anyone help with how do I solve this two equations to obtain this:

$$\theta = \arctan \left(\frac u{\sqrt{u^2+2gh}} \right)$$

Thanks. :)

P.S.: I did tried to solve by substituting R in equation (1), but my final answer way very long and very complicated.

Comment: Just replace all occurencies of $R$ in the first equation using the second equation, then solve the quadractic equation with respect to $\tan ^2\theta$.

Comment: @TZakrevskiy I did it the same way.. but it was way too complicated..

Comment: Look at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/571/what-is-the-optimum-angle-of-projection-when-throwing-a-stone-off-a-cliff

Comment: my result is also not yours, are you sure that you have made no typo?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner I pretty much sure... there is not typo

Comment: do you have a link of this problem?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner I am so sorry!! yes there is an typo. Really sorry.. just realized now!! Thank you very very much.. I jst editted the question.

Comment: Since $\cot \theta = 1/\tan \theta$, everything cancels out nicely. You shouldn't be getting anything complicated.

Comment: I suspect there is an error somewhere: $R$ is length, yet $\frac{g}{u^2}$ is $\frac{1}{\text{length}}$, hence the second equation has little sense.